# How to introduce the doxygen PREDEFINED tag in rosdoc_lite

Tags: ros, rosdoc-lite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanted that the following class protected by an #ifdef appears in the generated class list:

```
#ifdef HAVE_MY_LIBRARY
class myClass {
public;
  myClass(){};
};
#endif
```

With doxygen this could be achieved by putting PREDEFINED="HAVE_MY_LIBRARY" in the config file.

I haven't see how to do the same with rosdoc_lite ?

Regards
Fabien

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/154676/how-to-introduce-the-doxygen-predefined-tag-in-rosdoc_lite/) by [Fabien Spindler](https://answers.ros.org/users/3990/fabien-spindler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2014-04-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rosdoc_lite script does not attempt to provide all the features of every documentation builder. It merely provides a useful subset that can be run automatically on the ROS build farm.

The usual recommendation for those with complex documentation schemes is to use Doxygen (or Sphinx or Epydoc) directly, generating the docs yourself.

The Doxygen builder does provide a [set of tags](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdoc#Builder:_Doxygen) that you can modify. I don't see PREDEFINED in that list, but perhaps it could be added.

If you want to try doing that, please open an [enhancement issue](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdoc_lite/issues/new) with a link to this question, and provide a pull request, if possible.

**Update**: Fabien provided his requested enhancement. It is now released to Groovy, Hydro and Indigo. See: [ros-infrastructure/rosdoc_lite#47](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdoc_lite/issues/47).

Thanks for contributing!

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2